# How can I shut down Windows 7 from an iPhone over my LAN?

Tags: windows-7, iphone, shutdown, remote

Preferably something fast that doesn't require a extra service on Windows 7, but I'm open for any suggestions. Cydia and Apple app store available.

I am currently doing shutdown -s through RDP, but it's kinda cumbersome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [ServerControl](http://www.stratospherix.com/products/servercontrol/) iPhone app from Stratospherix Ltd.

> ServerControl allows you to reboot and shutdown your computers as well
>   as control their services remotely from your iPhone, wherever you are.
>
> REBOOT/SHUTDOWN
>
> - Immediate or delayed reboot/shutdown.
> - Choose whether running applications should be forced to close.
> - Choose from 4 editable messages to display to logged on users.
> - Efficient protocol use. Doesn't use RDP.
> - Can re-schedule a reboot/shutdown even if someone else has already scheduled one.
> - Windows machines only. Macs can not be rebooted or shutdown with ServerControl.

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing it's using http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770416.aspx which means I can create a small script to do it from my laptop too!